# Converting pack to perl6

Tags: raku

I would like to convert the following from perl5 to perl6,

```
$salt = pack "C*", map {int rand 256} 1..16;
```

It create a string of 16 characters where each character has a randomly picked value from 0 to 255. Perl5 doesn't assign any semantics to those characters, so they could be bytes, Unicode Code Points, or something else.

I think I can get by with

```
$salt = (map {(^256).pick.chr},^16).join;
```

But I got stuck on using pack, here is my attempt,

```
use experimental :pack;

my $salt = pack("C*",(map {(^256).pick} , ^16)).decode('utf-8');

say $salt;
say $salt.WHAT;
```

and results can be either an error,

```
Malformed termination of UTF-8 string  
      in block <unit> at test.p6 line 3
```

or something like,

```
  j
  (Str)
```

My line of thought is that packing the integer **List** would return a **Buf** then decoding that should produce the required **Str**.

**Update:**

As suggested on comment and answer `Buf` is the correct object to use.  Now to follow up on the `pack` part,

```
perl6 -e 'use experimental :pack; my $salt = pack("C*",(map {(^256).pick} , ^16));say $salt;say $salt.WHAT;'
```

Buf:0x<7D>
(Buf)

that only packed one unit

On the other hand, using P5pack (suggested by Scimon) returns an error

```
perl6 -e 'use P5pack; my $salt = pack("C*",(map {(^256).pick} , ^16));say $salt;say $salt.WHAT;'
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏*' (indicated by ⏏)
  in sub one at /home/david/.rakudobrew/moar-master/install/share/perl6/site/sources/D326BD5B05A67DBE51C279B9B9D9B448C6CDC401 (P5pack) line 166
  in sub pack at /home/david/.rakudobrew/moar-master/install/share/perl6/site/sources/D326BD5B05A67DBE51C279B9B9D9B448C6CDC401 (P5pack) line 210
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

**Update 2:**

I didn't spot the difference.

```
perl6 -e 'say (map {(^256).pick}, ^16).WHAT;'
(Seq)
perl6 -e 'say Buf.new((^256).roll(16)).WHAT;'  
(Buf)
```

Now make them lists,

```
perl6 -e 'use experimental :pack; my $salt = pack("C*",(Buf.new((^256).roll(16)).list));say $salt;say $salt.WHAT;'
    Buf:0x<39>
    (Buf)
```

And

```
perl6 -e 'use P5pack; my $salt = pack("C*",Buf.new((^256).roll(16)).list);say $salt;say $salt.WHAT;'
    Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏*' (indicated by ⏏)
      in sub one at /home/david/.rakudobrew/moar-master/install/share/perl6/site/sources/D326BD5B05A67DBE51C279B9B9D9B448C6CDC401 (P5pack) line 166
      in sub pack at /home/david/.rakudobrew/moar-master/install/share/perl6/site/sources/D326BD5B05A67DBE51C279B9B9D9B448C6CDC401 (P5pack) line 210
      in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

Reference:

[Buffers and Binary IO](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/buffers-and-binary-io/)

[A first approach to pack/unpack in Perl 6](https://gist.github.com/masak/1239203/8f36296ab264f1dc9c623bb7a66b4887d3b13ae3)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you want a random selection from the first 256 Unicode Code Points, use `decode('iso-8859-1')`. That's a weird thing to want, though. What makes you think it shouldn't be a `Buf`? If you're trying to generate an (insecure) crypto key, then you are generating arbitrary bytes, and a `Buf` would be the appropriate type.

Comment: @ikegami , thanks for your comment. >> What are you actually trying to do? - I saw that P5 line at a task on Rosetta Code and wanted to translate it to P6 as a learning process.

Comment: One note `^256.roll(16)` should give you 16 random numbers without needing the map. I'll take a look further once I'm up.

Comment: @Scimon thanks, you are right, please see my update 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ikegami says in a comment to your question, you really should use a `Buf`, which is basically a “string” of bytes.

```
my $salt = Buf.new((^256).roll(16));
```

You can write this to a file with something like:

```
spurt 'foo', $salt, :bin;
```

or encode it in base-64 with:

```
use MIME::Base64;
my $encoded = MIME::Base64.encode($salt);
```

But if you need this to be reasonably secure, have a look at [Crypt::Random](https://github.com/skinkade/crypt-random)

```
use Crypt::Random;
my $salt = crypt_random_buf(16);
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to probably to use https://modules.perl6.org/dist/P5pack:cpan:ELIZABETH which allows you to use Perl5 pack syntax.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and please see my update.  Perhaps I used it wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `"C" x 16`  works but not `"C*"`.  Don't ask, I don't know why either. :-D

```
perl6 -e 'use experimental :pack; my $salt = pack("C" x 16,(Buf.new((^256).roll(16)).list));say $salt;say $salt.WHAT;'
Buf:0x<64 71 D4 E6 E6 AD 7B 1C DD A2 62 CC DD DA F3 08>
(Buf)
```

On the other hand, unpack does work.

```
perl6 -e 'use experimental :pack; my $salt = pack("C" x 16,(Buf.new((^256).roll(16)).list)).unpack("C*");say $salt;say $salt.WHAT;'
(35 101 155 237 153 126 109 193 94 105 70 111 59 51 131 233)
(List)
```

All in all, mscha's answer is P6'ish and neat.  It was a silly round trip to `pack` a list of `Buf` to get a `Buf`.

As for the other pack conversions, note the two key points from [here](https://gist.github.com/masak/1239203/8f36296ab264f1dc9c623bb7a66b4887d3b13ae3),

```
Here is the difference between Perl 5 and Perl 6 pack/unpack:

Perl 5                      Perl 6

pack(List)  --> Str         pack(List)  --> Buf
unpack(Str) --> List        unpack(Buf) --> List
```

And

some Perl 5 template rules assume an uncomplicated two-way street between Buf and Str. There simply is no real distinction in Perl 5 between Buf and Str, and Perl 5 makes use of that quite a bit.

Edit: fix typo, s/masha/mscha/;

Comment: s/mascha/mscha/

Comment: sorry, typo fixed.